# Automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (verification)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-verification, ring-theory

Consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. If $f$ is an automorphism of this ring, then since $f(1)=1$ so $f$ fixes $\mathbb{Z}$. To determine $f(x)$, since $0$ is a root of this polynomial with multiplicity $1$ we have $f(x)=ax$ for some $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. Applying evaluation map, we get $a=1$. So the only automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is identity.

There could have been attempts to prove that the only automorphisms of the ring under consideration is identity; but my question is whether above proof is correct?

**Q.** Is this correct way to prove the assertion that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ only one ring automorphism? (my assertion may be wrong; I don't know in general what it should be.)

Comment: Why should an automorphism automatically be a polynomial without proof?

Comment: If f is a automorphism, you cannot talk about root because it is not a polynomial, it is just a function from the ring to itself.

Comment: @AdamHughes No, when I say "$f$ given by $x\mapsto x+1$", I implicitly mean that $f$ is the identity on the integers, since that's been established already. It sends the _element_ $x\in \Bbb Z[x]$ to the element $x+1\in \Bbb Z[x]$. $x$ is a specific element, not a placeholder for an arbitrary element. So $3 = f(3) = f(3) = 3$, but $x = f(x-1) = f(x)-f(1) = x+1-1 = x$.

Comment: @Arthur ah, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the value on the simplest polynomial, $q(x)=x$. Then if $f(x) = p(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$, by the ring homomorphism property, if $\deg p(x) =n > 1$ no non-constant polynomials have degree lower than $n$ and so $f$ cannot be onto unless $n=1$. So $f(x) = ax+b$. But then $f^{-1}(x) = a'x+b'$ is also a linear polynomial, so $a(a'x+b')+b=x$ i.e. $aa'=1$ so since they are integers, $a=a'\in \{\pm 1\}$. And then we have only that $b'=\pm b$ where the sign can be chosen appropriately, so $b$ can be arbitrary and we see any $f$ so that $f$ fixes $\Bbb Z$ pointwise and maps $x$ to $\pm x+b$ for any $b\in\Bbb Z$ uniquely determines an automorphism of $\Bbb Z[x]$ by extending using the homomorphism property.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the map
$$
a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n\mapsto
a_0+a_1(x+1)+\dots+a_n(x+1)^n
$$
is clearly an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$